# loop devices of removed apps

Tags: uninstall, snap

i am working on cleaning my system and found several "loop devices" in disks.

i found out that there are snaps installed (allthough i'm not sure what it means)

but they seem to be part of either tor browser (someting i tried out a while a go but uninstalled it almost immediately) and also matrouska tools which is something i don't even remember but couldn't find back.

and even though i uninstalled, autoremoved, and purged tor the snaps / loop devices are still there.

anyway it seems like they take up space and i would like to remove them.

i have found out how you can unmount them but i'm not clear on how to actually remove them.

also there seem to be a lot of questions on the issue but i didn't find anything that actually explains this a bit simple.

i did autoremove and purge and stuff but it still stays.

Matthieu

Comment: Autoremove and purge don't work with snaps. Those commands are for debs. Are you *sure* you uninstalled the snaps properly?

Comment: `sudo snap remove <name-of-snap>` removes snaps. refer https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy